# Unloadable minecraft world

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I have been playing a modpack with Galacticraft and when I was on the moon I placed a sealable aluminum cable block and after a few seconds my game has crashed. I can not load that world anymore. Is there any way to remove the block or change my dimension because I am ok with deleting the dimension and generating it again. I have no recent backups and it is not worth starting over because I played for years without backup. I would just stop playing that modpack.

Comment: I removed a dimension from my save but can I remove that block without loading it?

Comment: If you removed the entire dimension, everything in it should be gone.

Comment: It was generated again but I can not get back without cheating and I dont want to do that and I also want to keep stuff in that old one

Comment: Why can you not get back?

Comment: Dont have rocket launch pad and fuel loader blocks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is [requesting **troubleshooting and diagnosis of a modded Minecraft crash issue*](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10390/4797). We allow an exception for unmodded or 'Vanilla' Minecraft, please see [How do I ask a good Minecraft Bug/Crash question?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9943/4797)